# Restoring purchase of premium features after reinstall

Tags: applications, google-play-store, in-app-purchase

I was searching for a nice-looking Android app that can keep track of my expenses and I found [Expense Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=at.markushi.expensemanager). The app itself is free and it looks like it suits my needs, but it also has some premium features that I want. They can be unlocked through an in-app purchase. Before I pay money for them, I wanted to figure out how I can restore this purchase in case I ever have to reinstall the app after a factory reset.

Is there a standard procedure to restore this in-app purchase? Does it happen automatically? Do I have to do it manually through Google Play?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Applications often have a *Restore In-App Purchase* option in the settings.

Other applications may ask you to "buy again" the item, but you're not actually spending any money again.

It is often mentioned how you can restore your purchases in the application's description on Google Play or in the help category of the application (if any). You can always contact the developer for more information.

*(Note that we are talking about **Non-consumables** purchases, it means purchases that are permanently associated with one's google account. [More Information](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html#consumetypes).)*

Comment: I cannot find any sign of a 'Restore purchases' button. There's no documentation available as far as I can tell. How can I find out whether a purchase is a consumable or a non-consumable?

Comment: It is straitforward in theory : a virtual currency is a **consommable** and something lile a "remove ads" purchase is **non-consomable**, but in fact it all depends on the way it is programmed by the developer(s), so your best bet woild be to contact them.

Comment: I did contact the developer a few weeks ago, but unfortunately I did not hear back from them. If there's no other way to find out if the developer implemented premium features as a non-consumable, then I guess there's no way for me to find out beforehand.